# Integrating Thinktecture IdentityManager into existing site

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I have an existing MVC site that uses Identity and I would like to use Thinktecture IdentityManager. The problem is it comes with its own host based on OWIN and my site uses IIS. What is the best way to integrate Thinktecture IdentityManager into an existing site?

Thanks, Justin.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I gave up on IdentityManager I just dont have time to dig into the new OWIN stuff.

Comment: I found the identity sample project on codeplex and modified that. Also take a look at http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/20/ASPNET-Identity-20-Building-An-Extensible-Template-Project.aspx

Comment: Yeah, had to do the same -(

Comment: Did you come right Justin?